# Mapping a list of dictionaries from one type to another

Tags: python

I have list of dictonaries.  I wish type iterate over this list and map it to a slightly different type of dictionary.

Original dictionary:

```
{'Test Name':blah, 'Test': blah, 'Att a': blah, 'Att b': blah}
```

New Dictionary:

```
{'Test Name':blah, 'Test': blah, 'Failure': failure, 'Project': project}
```

In the original I only care about the attributes Test Name and Test.  In the new dictionary, I add a few extra attributes.

To do this, I do:

```
mappedFailures = []; 
for fixedFailure in fixedFailures:
    mappedFailure = {'Test Suite': fixedFailure['Test Suite'], 
                     'Test':fixedFailure['Test'], 'Failure':failure, 
                     'Project': 'project'}
    mappedFailures.append(mappedFailure);
```

This is easy to read, but I was wondering was there a more pythonic way Thanks.

Comment: Python 3 includes dict comprehensions, which are designed for this kind of use case.  See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/

Comment: The first 'pythonic' thing to do is to drop the semicolons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic use case for a list comprehension:

```
def map_failure(ff):
    return {'Test Suite': ff['Test Suite'], 'Test': ff['Test'],
            'Failure': failure, 'Project': 'project'}

mappedFailures = [map_failure(ff) for ff in fixedFailures]
```

Comment: Is there any particular benefit to defining a method just to return a dict?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a list comprehension and the [dict constructor](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) to achieve the very short

```
mappedFailures = dict((key, fixedFailure[key]) for key in ('Test Name', 'Test'))
mappedFailures['Failure'] = failure
mappedFailures['Project'] = project
```

Comment: There's really no need to iterate over the whole dictionary. You can just pick the keys that you need: `dict((key, fixedFailure[key]) for key in ('Test Name', 'Test'))`

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `mappedFailures` is actually a list of dicts. For that, you simply want to use list comprehension to iterate over each `fixedFailure` and build a new dict from that.

```
mappedFailures = [
    {
        'Test Name': fixedFailure['Test Name'],
        'Test':      fixedFailure['Test'],
        'Failure':   failure,
        'Project':   project,
    }
    for fixedFailure in fixedFailures
]
```